# Data Reader error using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, entity-framework, windows-phone-7

I'm in the process of building a WCF Service Application which connects to an SQL Database using Entity SQL (Entity Framework). At the moment I keep getting this error with several methods:

*The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.*

This is an example of one of the methods and would appreciate some advice on how to approach this:

```
public string[] Tables()
    {
        string Sql = @"SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables";

        using (var Context = new XEntities())
        {
            Context.Database.Connection.Open();

            IEnumerable<string> Query = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(Sql);              
            string[] results = Query.ToArray();

            Context.Database.Connection.Close();

            return results;

        }
```

The method is supposed to query the database for a list of tables and send them back in an array. This will then be inputted into a ListBox by the Windows Phone App.

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query to select the column you want to populate `Query` with:

```
string Sql = @"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables";
```